# How does work the chinese adjectives?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I'd like to know how work the chinese adjectives, because i was searching on the internet about this, but i wasn't able to understand the use of 的 and if any noun can become a adjective, if yes is it be this case 为人民服务 because when translate split it means like people service or like that.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you can use 的 or not use 的 to describe things. For example: 她就是那個穿著墨綠色衣服的溫柔女生，總是為別人著想。 in English: She is that tender female dress in dark green who always care about others. In this example, 穿著墨綠色衣服 used to describe somethings after 的(女生). 墨綠色 used to describe something after 墨綠色(衣服). And 溫柔 used to describe something after 溫柔(女生).